# Got warnings while installing Eslint in Atom editor

Tags: node.js, react-native, atom-editor, eslint

I am using Atom editor for React native. I am trying to install eslint. But got some warnings while running npm install commannd.

Firstly I have install both linter-eslint and eslint packages in Atom.

I have created a file .eslintrc and put below piece of code
{
  “extends”: “eslint-config-google”
}

I have run the command npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding from root level of my project. But got below warnings and eslint is not working as well.

```
npm WARN deprecated eslint-plugin-class-property@1.1.0: please use eslint-plugin-babel and babel/semi
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.12.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\ReactNative\albums\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.0.1 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@2.2.3 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@1.16.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@6.10.3 requires a peer of eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I have also tried to uninstall packages and re-install them but its not working.